# Image is chopped while generating PDF from PieCharts (Amchart)

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I want to export my pie chart as pdf , everything is fine when results are limited to 5-6, after that image is chopping in PDF See the image below 
[Chopped Image in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPDwm.png)

The Problem I am getting is because we are using Scrollbar if result is large See the image below 
[Generating Pie Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJsyx.png).Due to this scroll bar we are not able to capture the image of the report hence we are getting the chopped image. Can anyone help me with this issue. Below is the code we are using for generating pdf from piecharts

```
    // Collect actual chart objects out of the AmCharts.charts array
    var ids = ["chartdiv-" +data.id];
    var charts = {}
    var charts_remaining = ids.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < AmCharts.charts.length; x++) {
            if(!(charts[ids[i]])){
                if (AmCharts.charts[x].div.id == ids[i])
                    if(this.criteria.fullView && AmCharts.charts[x].container.height > 290 && AmCharts.charts[x].container.height != 330 && document.body.contains(AmCharts.charts[x].containerDiv))
                        charts[ids[i]] = AmCharts.charts[x];
                    else if(AmCharts.charts[x].container.height == 330 && this.criteria.dashBoard && document.body.contains(AmCharts.charts[x].containerDiv))
                        charts[ids[i]] = AmCharts.charts[x];
                    else if(!this.criteria.fullView && !this.criteria.dashBoard && AmCharts.charts[x].container.height > 290 && document.body.contains(AmCharts.charts[x].containerDiv))
                        charts[ids[i]] = AmCharts.charts[x];
            }
        }
    }

    // Trigger export of each chart
    for (var x in charts) {
        if (charts.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            var chart = charts[x];
            chart.export.capture({}, function() {
                this.toJPG({ multiplier: 2  }, function(data) {

                    // Save chart data into chart object itself
                    this.setup.chart.exportedImage = data;

                    // Reduce the remaining counter
                    charts_remaining--;

                    // Check if we got all of the charts
                    if (charts_remaining == 0) {
                        // Yup, we got all of them
                        // Let's proceed to putting PDF together
                        generatePDF();
                    }

                });
            });
        }
    }

    function generatePDF() {
        var id = divId;
        var layout = {
            "content": []
        }
        layout.content.push(
            {"text": name, "fontSize": 13,  "fit": [ 523.28, 769.89 ]},
            {
                "image": charts["chartdiv-"+id].exportedImage,
                "width" : 40,
                "fit": fitParam
            }, { "text": content, "fontSize": 10});

        chart["export"].toPDF(layout, function(data) {
            this.download(data, "application/pdf", "amCharts.pdf");
        });



    }
};
```

Comment: Try `{"text": name, "fontSize": 13,  "fit": [ 523.28, 769.89 ], "margin" : [0, 0, 0, 0]}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Viney , but it is still not working